# Count gaps between polygon in spatialite

Tags: spatialite, spatial-query

I have a database (.db) with a table that contains thousands of polygons containing id and geometry. I like a query that can get me the 'number of errors where there are gaps between polygons".

How can I prepare such a query ? What GIS function I can use ?

let's suppose table structure ::

table name : temp1

column name ::
id (integer) : POLYGON_ID
geometry

Comment: Same question on spatialite mailing list at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spatialite-users/Z2TLVMVXcs4. Perhaps you can update this question with the same information I asked for there.